# Editor to wiki text

Tags: editor, wikipedia, wiki

I search to an **editior** to **wikipedia** that may could convert regular text such as office document to wiki text or(wiki markup codes), I mean formats remain but being a wiki code such like this:
if a text in the .doc is header1, then it converts to wiki code header1 like this:

## Header 1

converts to
`=Header1=`

and so on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:WordToWiki. If you use Visual editor in your wiki, then you can simply paste your text from word to the editing interface, and it will convert it to wiki markup immediately. The link above contains some methods to help you convert word document to wiki markup if you don't use visual editor.